# Interpreting post raster to polygon conversion data from ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-conversion

I'm trying to map out a bathymetric map of Hong Kong, and so I downloaded this data from the internet which included an .asc2 file and a .tiff file which should supposedly have information that will allow me to make a bathymetric map. But when I opened the asc2 file, the format was different from what I've seen in tutorials and guides (see below). So I edited it so that it looks like the below data. Then on arcmap, after starting a new map, I opened up the ASC2 to raster tool, then I put the .asc file in the input and just gave the name 'test' for the output and left the output data type as integer. I clicked okay but an error came up. Then I tried the .tif file; I opened up the raster to polygon tool (not sure if its the best for what I want to do), put the .tif file as the input, left 'Field' as it was, put 't' for the output. Deselected simplify polygons. Pressed 'Ok'. Then ended up with the below resutls.

[image]

I opened up the attribute table but the data doesn't really look like it can help me to map out water depths(?). I tried playing with the symbology and came up with this:

[image]

As you can see, there are a ton of values, a lot of which are negative numbers, so I don't know how I can make a map showing different depths. This looks like the type of data that is not for analysis or measurement. Do I have the wrong type of data for what I'm trying to do? Please do provide guidance as I'm very new to GIS.

Error when trying to convert asc2 to raster:

[image]

ASC2 file:

```
ncols 80

nrows 61

xllcorner 113.796500000000

yllcorner 22.084500000000

dx 0.008378750000

dy 0.008377049180

NODATA_value -32768

-6 -6 -5 -3 2 22 8 26 14 7 11 39 33 26 27 59 50 20 16 19 33 46 52 86 133 154 208 234 246 209 161 205 123 163 177 89 41 27 72 61 81 53 36 48 90 124 154 182 404 675 524 228 86 33 24 7 8 12 28 64 3 -15 -20 -22 -13 -5 -8 -10 -8 -9 -14 -15 -12 -11 -10 -1 16 91 113 78
 -6 -5 -4 -3 -1 2 3 5 7 7 12 18 19 15 24 40 49 26 32 77 98 203 217 238 205 148 146 147 130 146 71 85 113 64 167 88 29 21 46 42 32 28 38 61 98 233 397 378 502 693 602 316 128 113 24 6 3 -1 -1 -1 -13 -20 -22 -20 -14 -9 -8 -8 -7 -8 -10 -10 -6 -8 -14 -12 27 92 46 108
 -5 -4 -3 -3 -2 -1 3 3 5 6 9 14 17 15 20 37 29 16 12 25 80 184 143 220 223 146 108 38 30 34 28 28 39 56 42 34 24 13 21 40 28 21 54 72 80 230 493 561 390 330 294 202 179 56 4 2 1 1 -4 -10 -16 -18 -18 -16 -10 -6 -7 -7 -7 -8 -9 -9 -8 -10 -12 -9 4 6 5 49
 -4 -3 -2 -2 -1 -1 1 -1 -1 1 6 7 10 16 20 25 25 17 11 15 25 34 57 158 118 57 62 35 24 23 36 21 20 44 24 24 17 12 23 44 18 16 61 27 39 86 206 238 218 125 138 49 16 2 -1 -3 -4 -5 -5 -6 -8 -10 -12 -12 -8 -5 -6 -7 -8 -8 -9 -10 -10 -11 -9 -5 -1 -1 -1 34
 -4 -3 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 3 -1 1 6 5 16 26 27 22 21 10 11 16 27 55 89 49 27 20 20 25 20 32 19 10 20 20 17 18 12 19 21 15 24 18 27 70 61 121 125 213 111 25 10 2 -5 -5 -2 -2 -3 4 4 1 1 -5 -8 -8 -7 -7 -8 -8 -9 -10 -11 -12 -11 -6 2 -2 -6 -7 5
 -3 -2 -1 -1 6 -1 -1 -2 -3 -3 1 -1 1 14 18 22 17 12 6 7 14 25 27 34 31 19 10 16 23 10 6 10 7 17 18 11 15 18 15 11 13 22 14 38 111 93 219 323 281 70 6 4 2 24 25 1 -2 -3 2 9 20 6 -1 -3 -5 -8 -9 -9 -9 -10 -11 -12 -13 -13 -5 11 -1 -9 -18 -19
 -3 -3 -2 -1 -1 -1 -1 -3 -5 -6 -6 -4 1 7 10 22 8 3 2 6 13 20 19 20 19 10 11 12 16 7 6 13 8 15 9 7 8 13 13 11 26 7 11 24 67 185 267 245 100 15 -1 -6 33 113 53 23 -3 -3 10 15 12 3 4 -4 -9 -11 -11 -10 -10 -10 -12 -13 -14 -14 -9 2 7 -12 -21 -23
 -3 -3 -2 -1 -1 -1 -2 -4 -7 -8 -8 -6 -1 4 12 7 -1 -1 -2 2 -1 1 2 5 2 3 8 10 13 11 12 10 7 3 -1 7 16 17 36 27 35 16 10 16 62 79 57 40 37 1 11 32 34 132 123 25 2 8 -1 -1 1 27 14 -7 -15 -14 -12 -10 -9 -10 -12 -14 -15 -15 -13 -12 -14 -17 -21 -19
 -3 -3 -2 -1 1 -1 -3 -6 -8 -8 -5 -1 -1 6 9 3 -1 -1 -3 -3 -3 -1 -1 -2 -2 -1 1 8 11 11 10 7 4 2 16 23 74 21 12 42 48 47 33 20 36 34 53 86 82 21 22 106 141 182 91 54 51 25 1 -5 -2 31 4 -2 -13 -14 -12 -9 -8 -10 -14 -15 -16 -17 -17 -18 -20 -23 -24 -19
 -3 -2 -2 -1 2 22 -4 -7 -8 -6 -1 9 13 11 10 4 -1 -2 -3 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -2 -1 1 3 5 6 4 1 11 58 30 24 5 6 6 31 49 33 13 22 35 153 224 149 117 120 117 151 214 247 206 22 7 -3 5 12 28 5 4 4 -9 -9 -7 -7 -12 -16 -17 -18 -19 -20 -22 -26 -29 -32 -31
 -2 -2 -2 -1 2 1 -6 -8 -1 -1 1 56 151 39 14 5 -1 -2 -4 -5 -5 -5 -5 -5 -4 -2 -1 -1 1 2 2 3 -1 4 21 26 8 7 9 15 11 8 12 27 54 56 241 344 282 279 249 172 98 118 128 94 56 90 54 14 8 16 45 38 3 -1 3 13 -9 -13 -16 -17 -18 -20 -22 -25 -29 -34 -39 -41
 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 1 -9 1 20 40 12 125 147 20 13 6 -1 -2 -4 -5 -5 -5 -5 -4 -2 -1 -1 1 -1 -1 -1 6 5 11 62 56 16 22 17 15 18 18 60 159 131 137 339 415 440 434 333 266 152 111 204 215 192 145 136 149 90 105 46 -1 -1 -1 2 5 -8 -11 -14 -16 -17 -20 -23 -26 -31 -36 -39 -39
 -3 -3 -4 -4 -5 -7 -9 -5 12 135 68 103 54 4 3 8 -1 -4 -6 -6 -5 -3 -2 2 9 2 -1 1 -2 -2 2 20 18 28 81 54 19 40 20 63 58 22 84 176 234 193 176 244 429 382 409 421 237 15 38 61 20 8 34 152 98 13 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 7 -2 -6 -11 -14 -16 -19 -22 -26 -31 -35 -37 -33
 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -4 3 14 10 62 8 1 -8 -4 -5 -7 -8 -7 -3 -1 -1 12 15 1 -1 1 1 2 2 14 28 63 169 72 19 37 79 143 94 91 32 106 320 228 189 198 191 106 133 150 95 7 6 6 6 8 54 47 12 1 9 1 3 1 11 47 -2 -7 -10 -12 -14 -17 -21 -26 -30 -33 -35 -30
 -5 -6 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 -9 1 2 13 11 2 -9 -10 -9 -10 -11 -11 -8 -1 -1 10 20 4 -1 -1 1 -1 2 5 45 58 142 284 223 98 58 201 314 246 79 27 113 216 122 159 56 26 7 11 6 9 6 6 21 20 19 3 -2 3 67 109 13 14 15 -1 19 -7 -11 -10 -11 -12 -15 -20 -24 -29 -33 -35 -33
 -7 -8 -8 -8 -8 -9 -9 -9 -9 -5 1 1 -4 -8 -8 -9 -13 -15 -14 -7 -1 4 9 12 12 12 11 4 1 -1 24 169 232 373 429 263 93 157 336 374 127 25 43 103 71 22 19 48 14 -10 1 -6 1 5 8 11 1 -3 -5 -20 32 222 177 29 28 21 -1 3 -9 -15 -12 -9 -9 -13 -18 -24 -29 -33 -37 -39
 -9 -11 -10 -10 -9 -8 -8 -8 -8 -7 -5 -6 -7 -7 -5 -8 -15 -16 -12 -1 6 39 8 9 18 18 17 7 4 1 4 15 59 149 172 63 111 265 389 176 50 43 30 17 15 8 5 11 1 13 3 25 -1 5 13 -3 -3 -1 11 31 64 208 118 113 46 -1 -1 41 18 -20 -15 -5 -6 -12 -18 -23 -28 -33 -38 -43
 -12 -14 -13 -11 -9 -7 -6 -5 -6 -6 -8 -9 -10 -9 -8 -12 -18 -12 4 27 74 61 10 5 10 11 11 14 8 11 2 2 9 11 15 24 110 352 245 75 56 111 80 39 15 5 -1 -1 -7 2 1 -3 -4 -5 -5 -7 -6 18 55 114 149 185 152 138 62 -1 16 91 4 -25 -16 -4 -9 -15 -19 -23 -27 -32 -38 -43
 -13 -16 -14 -11 -8 -6 -4 -2 -3 -6 -9 -12 -13 -12 -12 -19 -20 3 38 95 192 112 15 7 11 14 6 6 7 39 27 4 5 11 15 27 91 230 158 143 197 224 167 56 102 89 18 20 -1 -10 -16 -15 1 1 -1 -3 -4 4 57 170 355 304 183 58 8 16 22 159 47 37 67 20 -12 -18 -19 -22 -26 -30 -35 -40
 -4 -12 -9 -8 -6 -4 -2 -1 -2 -5 -9 -13 -15 -9 -4 -14 -12 25 107 184 210 85 10 16 64 24 7 7 17 106 107 51 7 12 19 38 58 169 361 343 414 446 292 117 191 186 206 95 4 -3 -20 2 11 26 34 15 5 -1 28 98 298 308 223 69 28 60 23 146 163 260 198 54 -15 -16 -16 -20 -24 -28 -32 -36
 29 6 -1 -1 -2 -2 -1 -1 -2 -4 -8 -12 -14 2 7 12 16 69 224 205 44 15 11 43 190 85 12 17 20 46 161 58 11 25 65 150 148 238 496 632 632 555 392 248 364 269 293 157 88 27 1 18 88 205 184 57 4 35 140 127 220 187 324 203 178 72 42 120 85 93 53 53 6 -11 -13 -17 -22 -26 -29 -32
 181 58 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -2 -5 -7 3 36 115 138 66 124 233 129 18 13 38 104 220 107 22 46 70 152 181 56 62 149 210 338 383 502 744 758 595 605 460 466 480 341 276 188 119 12 3 71 257 444 356 195 82 109 275 190 240 122 125 112 191 266 148 199 87 4 -1 11 11 -8 -13 -17 -21 -24 -26 -28
 65 102 9 -1 -2 -2 -2 -1 -1 -1 -3 -4 22 22 92 169 121 149 165 50 19 23 112 232 257 206 118 86 134 133 127 209 249 242 389 413 435 498 694 742 483 399 308 424 465 295 186 157 45 8 36 98 231 326 478 269 200 86 193 134 126 157 28 96 244 301 191 108 71 -13 -16 -16 -8 -10 -14 -17 -20 -22 -24 -26
 -2 -1 -9 -8 -7 -5 -3 -2 -1 -2 -4 -8 -10 4 63 176 175 250 302 73 24 41 220 294 321 272 214 142 111 96 147 237 361 335 436 398 309 376 436 534 449 272 248 349 347 232 136 38 7 53 202 161 239 373 341 148 132 35 44 96 78 104 35 112 154 198 222 153 43 38 -16 -17 -12 -12 -15 -18 -20 -22 -23 -24
 -11 -10 -13 -11 -9 -6 -4 -2 -1 -1 -5 -12 -17 -10 6 154 226 256 360 60 14 25 260 388 335 240 139 78 100 152 227 230 259 337 377 250 187 274 257 304 289 226 269 338 216 157 82 11 13 59 208 270 262 310 272 92 22 2 2 12 35 2 36 130 72 83 116 97 128 192 66 -1 -8 -13 -16 -19 -20 -21 -22 -22
 -7 -9 -11 -10 -8 -6 -4 -2 -1 7 2 -12 -18 -13 27 130 181 176 156 18 4 19 86 105 81 55 62 71 170 218 224 192 181 308 364 246 103 88 108 101 121 192 235 186 59 34 17 13 31 56 156 352 400 285 107 48 18 -1 -1 -2 4 7 4 44 45 54 70 73 101 87 69 -1 -5 -14 -18 -19 -20 -21 -21 -22
 -3 -6 -8 -8 -7 -5 -3 -1 -1 3 -3 -10 -14 -10 5 28 69 57 27 15 13 -6 7 10 37 52 49 134 234 193 115 83 106 87 128 73 15 16 27 48 63 188 210 138 74 13 40 101 176 178 285 395 414 239 84 16 29 -1 -1 -2 7 20 5 -1 25 63 59 59 101 15 43 -1 -10 -16 -18 -19 -20 -20 -21 -21
 -4 -6 -7 -7 -6 -4 -3 -1 -1 -1 -3 -8 -11 -12 -10 -1 -1 1 4 -26 -24 1 -15 5 6 9 20 135 124 36 18 4 10 3 17 14 17 13 51 39 93 251 246 155 40 87 182 260 310 309 392 273 207 162 48 2 20 4 -1 -1 6 53 12 2 69 153 92 64 62 20 1 -9 -12 -15 -17 -18 -19 -19 -20 -20
 -5 -6 -6 -6 -5 -4 -2 -1 -1 -1 1 -5 -8 -9 -10 -9 -9 -16 -24 -26 -22 -18 -16 -13 -12 -11 7 20 2 -1 2 4 -3 8 116 80 27 6 16 48 188 191 159 183 216 250 339 275 296 357 466 291 75 29 14 12 15 9 -3 -1 29 118 93 5 7 70 67 29 44 -9 -12 -11 -12 -14 -16 -17 -17 -18 -19 -19
 -6 -6 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 -1 -1 1 -2 -3 -3 -5 -8 -11 -15 -18 -17 -13 -10 -11 -13 -14 -15 -10 -1 -1 21 5 10 -7 -1 31 101 97 9 6 60 80 105 158 194 235 147 114 76 92 167 434 269 171 160 125 79 1 -4 -9 -11 9 54 65 -1 -1 4 32 11 -6 -11 -12 -11 -12 -14 -15 -16 -16 -17 -17 -18
 -7 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -5 -8 -10 -10 -7 -3 -3 -8 -10 -6 -5 -10 -1 32 124 41 -7 -16 -17 1 100 109 -1 2 6 17 21 17 37 46 35 43 23 23 86 274 257 237 239 259 111 13 -1 -6 -7 -7 -3 90 19 1 -1 13 17 2 -8 -11 -12 -13 -13 -14 -15 -15 -16 -16 -17
 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -4 -1 -2 -6 -10 -5 -1 12 18 35 77 154 44 -8 -21 -20 1 31 17 -1 -1 5 3 2 7 16 20 19 21 9 8 33 104 169 259 137 79 115 48 -1 -1 20 1 -1 41 43 -6 -2 -1 5 5 1 -11 -12 -13 -13 -13 -14 -14 -14 -15 -16
 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -3 -1 -1 -1 -2 -3 -2 -1 -1 -1 -1 2 1 -3 -4 -9 -12 -8 1 48 130 116 156 12 39 14 -11 -22 -23 -17 -3 -1 -4 1 6 14 2 2 15 25 37 29 7 7 18 68 93 191 143 48 36 40 30 18 7 2 -2 -5 -7 -5 11 28 15 2 -8 -12 -13 -13 -13 -13 -12 -12 -13 -14 -15
 -9 -9 -8 -7 -6 -4 -2 -1 -1 -5 -6 -4 -3 1 4 4 6 -1 -1 -4 -13 -7 2 14 148 138 89 45 17 -4 -8 -16 -20 -20 -17 -11 -8 -9 -8 -6 -4 -7 -9 7 27 46 31 1 -1 4 26 36 101 189 85 15 68 141 77 3 2 -1 -3 -8 -6 2 -3 28 11 -10 -13 -14 -13 -13 -12 -11 -10 -11 -12 -14
 -10 -9 -9 -9 -8 -7 -4 -1 -3 -10 -11 1 3 3 -5 1 2 -1 -1 -1 -4 12 120 247 225 38 1 -1 -9 -12 -12 -13 -14 -14 -13 -12 -11 -11 -12 -12 -13 -17 -18 6 23 13 13 2 -1 1 1 30 91 139 18 7 52 151 90 49 101 5 -2 -8 -8 -7 -7 -5 -8 -14 -14 -14 -13 -12 -10 -8 -8 -9 -11 -14
 -10 -10 -10 -10 -11 -11 -11 -10 -13 -21 -18 1 5 3 3 9 9 -1 13 81 35 32 209 361 230 61 10 -4 -7 -6 -6 -6 -6 -7 -8 -9 -9 -9 -8 -7 -14 -21 -22 1 19 6 -4 4 5 1 -12 1 26 118 19 1 11 114 169 134 169 16 -10 -12 -10 -9 -9 -9 -11 -13 -14 -14 -13 -11 -9 -7 -7 -9 -11 -14
 -10 -10 -11 -12 -14 -17 -21 -24 -26 -30 -18 20 40 93 39 1 14 45 177 282 173 79 175 269 192 176 19 -1 5 9 -1 -1 -1 7 -4 -6 -6 -4 -1 7 35 38 24 1 1 -12 5 88 120 47 18 -16 14 21 -5 -6 3 74 66 16 14 -17 -17 -14 -10 -8 -7 -8 -10 -12 -13 -13 -13 -12 -10 -8 -8 -10 -12 -14
 -10 -10 -11 -12 -15 -20 -27 -30 -21 -24 20 82 217 261 201 13 26 131 325 485 406 223 154 121 142 186 53 -1 2 5 -1 -1 -1 2 -4 -7 -8 -4 93 101 212 295 123 46 36 30 29 135 258 111 96 39 30 -15 -19 2 19 46 104 10 1 2 -11 -12 -8 -4 -4 -6 -9 -11 -13 -13 -13 -13 -12 -11 -11 -12 -14 -16
 -10 -11 -12 -12 -12 -17 -27 -28 8 28 48 300 459 474 220 31 134 156 184 383 606 234 47 21 25 93 23 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -3 -6 -11 -14 -11 30 117 319 367 343 257 187 83 65 197 316 268 337 208 61 5 1 -9 3 34 57 68 10 -2 -8 -9 -5 4 -1 -4 -8 -11 -13 -14 -14 -14 -14 -14 -14 -15 -16 -18
 -12 -13 -13 -13 -11 -10 3 4 129 288 105 210 433 591 256 190 141 367 519 543 577 277 71 34 22 1 1 -5 -3 6 20 -2 -3 -5 -8 -12 -18 -20 -7 31 174 334 317 199 266 272 185 274 246 233 367 165 53 80 28 -3 1 2 -1 15 4 -11 -13 -9 -4 5 -1 -4 -8 -11 -13 -15 -16 -17 -17 -17 -17 -18 -19 -20
 -14 -15 -16 -16 -13 -7 12 8 98 280 275 296 442 474 550 419 287 463 694 543 369 170 138 117 83 4 -1 12 74 19 -2 -4 -5 -6 -8 -10 -14 -19 -26 2 78 170 136 112 106 109 141 261 279 133 167 153 214 181 73 -8 -6 2 47 29 -11 -16 -15 -11 -5 3 4 -6 -9 -13 -15 -17 -18 -19 -20 -20 -21 -21 -22 -22
 -15 -17 -19 -20 -18 -12 25 83 103 94 218 227 231 412 644 465 398 314 340 207 139 44 147 63 2 -1 -2 -4 10 24 -4 -6 -7 -7 -7 -7 -7 -6 -11 -17 3 17 28 21 58 40 47 266 192 105 40 80 173 52 3 -23 -11 10 112 66 -12 -17 -16 -13 -9 -6 -6 -9 -13 -16 -18 -20 -21 -22 -23 -23 -24 -24 -25 -25
 -16 -18 -20 -19 -14 4 92 288 218 208 281 105 127 349 349 190 281 111 77 43 9 7 77 59 7 1 -1 -4 -3 -3 -6 -7 -7 -7 -6 -5 1 16 28 -9 -17 2 47 13 107 6 31 50 177 224 95 20 104 124 4 -24 -17 -6 2 -11 -13 -17 -17 -15 -13 -12 -13 -15 -17 -19 -21 -23 -24 -25 -26 -27 -27 -28 -28 -28
 -16 -18 -19 -16 5 61 134 285 341 304 178 43 94 172 139 56 41 3 -12 -20 -23 33 191 132 106 61 2 -1 -3 -5 -7 -8 -8 -7 -6 -5 -2 28 32 -1 -10 -12 -10 3 15 -1 1 14 203 158 31 14 64 108 6 -20 -18 -12 -13 -15 -16 -17 -18 -17 -17 -17 -19 -21 -22 -24 -25 -26 -28 -29 -30 -31 -31 -31 -31 -31
 -15 -17 -17 -11 7 79 311 354 345 127 23 12 94 52 8 5 -1 -3 -18 -28 -22 4 109 69 85 10 -1 21 3 -4 -7 -8 -9 -8 -7 -5 7 15 49 19 6 -1 -9 -10 -11 -7 -5 11 66 26 -1 -6 18 153 59 -1 -12 -13 -14 -15 -15 -17 -18 -19 -20 -22 -25 -26 -27 -28 -29 -30 -31 -32 -33 -34 -34 -35 -35 -35
 -15 -17 -16 -10 1 81 276 188 125 15 -40 1 37 73 49 44 -5 -5 -12 -23 -22 -2 8 1 2 -1 -1 11 -1 -3 -8 -10 -10 -10 -9 -7 -8 -7 22 37 1 4 9 1 -13 -8 3 12 21 14 13 -11 -16 128 74 1 -7 -11 -12 -12 -14 -16 -18 -20 -23 -26 -30 -32 -32 -32 -32 -33 -33 -35 -36 -37 -37 -37 -37 -38
 -14 -16 -16 -12 -3 18 74 30 9 -30 -39 -20 -1 1 -1 -5 -8 -9 -13 -18 -18 -10 4 -1 -1 -1 5 16 15 -6 -10 -12 -12 -12 -12 -11 -10 -3 19 32 133 34 24 1 -13 -11 -8 -2 -1 55 46 -7 -11 7 3 -4 -10 -10 -8 -9 -11 -14 -17 -21 -24 -28 -32 -34 -34 -34 -34 -35 -35 -36 -37 -38 -38 -38 -38 -39
 -12 -15 -16 -13 -6 4 4 -25 -24 -24 -21 -14 -5 -2 -4 -7 -9 -10 -11 -13 -12 1 75 5 -1 -1 5 1 -6 -10 -12 -13 -14 -14 -14 -13 -9 -1 39 165 53 3 -8 -11 -14 -13 -11 -5 -1 28 40 -10 -12 -7 -7 -13 -14 -9 -4 -4 -8 -13 -17 -21 -25 -28 -32 -34 -35 -36 -36 -36 -37 -37 -37 -37 -37 -37 -37 -38
 -7 -14 -18 -15 -9 -7 -14 -21 -20 -11 -6 -5 6 6 -2 -6 -9 -10 -10 -11 -10 -5 9 3 -2 -7 -9 -9 -10 -12 -13 -15 -15 -16 -16 -15 -9 7 92 179 21 20 -7 -11 -14 -14 -13 -9 -7 -7 -10 -14 -9 52 80 -11 -14 -7 22 -2 -7 -12 -17 -21 -24 -28 -31 -34 -35 -37 -37 -38 -37 -37 -36 -36 -36 -36 -35 -35
 6 -14 -21 -18 -14 -11 -11 -12 -12 -8 -3 -1 4 6 1 -5 -10 -11 -10 -10 -11 -10 -9 -9 -11 -12 -10 -10 -11 -12 -14 -15 -16 -17 -18 -17 -13 1 19 19 11 -8 -7 -12 -15 -15 -15 -14 -17 -17 -17 -19 -13 12 20 26 12 -7 8 -6 -10 -14 -17 -21 -24 -27 -30 -33 -35 -37 -38 -38 -37 -36 -35 -34 -34 -33 -33 -33
 17 -11 -19 -18 -17 -15 -12 -11 -9 -6 -3 -1 -1 10 -1 -5 -9 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -9 -9 -11 -11 -11 -10 -11 -13 -14 -16 -17 -18 -19 -19 -19 -18 -18 -12 -9 -13 -13 -15 -17 -18 -19 -21 -23 -23 -23 -24 -21 -1 60 148 84 -10 -14 -13 -14 -16 -19 -21 -24 -27 -29 -32 -35 -37 -39 -39 -37 -35 -33 -32 -31 -31 -30 -30
 3 -3 -10 -16 -19 -18 -16 -13 -10 -8 -4 1 32 13 -1 -4 -8 -10 -10 -10 -10 -9 -8 -8 -10 -11 -11 -11 -11 -13 -14 -16 -18 -19 -20 -21 -22 -23 -23 -21 -18 -18 -19 -19 -20 -20 -21 -23 -25 -26 -26 -26 -23 -11 23 55 26 -12 -18 -18 -18 -19 -20 -22 -24 -26 -28 -30 -33 -36 -37 -37 -35 -32 -30 -29 -29 -28 -28 -28
 -2 -1 20 -14 -20 -22 -20 -17 -15 -12 -8 -4 3 -1 -2 -7 -10 -11 -12 -11 -11 -10 -9 -9 -10 -10 -10 -10 -11 -12 -14 -16 -18 -20 -21 -22 -23 -24 -24 -23 -22 -22 -22 -22 -22 -23 -23 -25 -26 -26 -26 -25 -22 -12 1 1 -1 -14 -19 -20 -20 -20 -22 -23 -25 -26 -27 -29 -31 -33 -34 -34 -32 -30 -28 -27 -27 -26 -26 -26
 -2 -1 15 11 -17 -23 -23 -21 -19 -17 -14 -11 -8 -6 -9 -12 -13 -13 -13 -13 -12 -12 -11 -10 -10 -10 -10 -9 -10 -12 -14 -17 -18 -20 -21 -22 -23 -24 -24 -24 -24 -24 -24 -24 -24 -24 -25 -26 -26 -26 -26 -24 -21 -16 -10 -5 -8 -15 -18 -20 -20 -22 -23 -25 -26 -27 -27 -28 -30 -31 -31 -32 -31 -28 -26 -26 -26 -26 -25 -26
 -6 2 84 95 1 -24 -24 -21 -20 -18 -17 -15 -13 -13 -14 -15 -16 -16 -16 -15 -14 -14 -13 -12 -11 -9 -8 -7 -7 -10 -14 -17 -19 -20 -21 -22 -23 -24 -25 -25 -25 -25 -25 -26 -26 -26 -26 -27 -27 -26 -25 -23 -21 -17 -14 -11 -12 -15 -18 -20 -22 -24 -26 -27 -29 -31 -31 -31 -32 -33 -32 -34 -33 -30 -29 -30 -30 -29 -28 -27
 -9 5 103 22 -14 -21 -21 -18 -16 -12 3 3 -12 -17 -18 -19 -18 -18 -18 -17 -16 -16 -14 -13 -11 -8 -5 -1 -1 -7 -13 -17 -19 -20 -21 -23 -24 -25 -25 -25 -26 -26 -26 -27 -27 -27 -28 -28 -27 -26 -25 -23 -20 -18 -15 -14 -14 -16 -18 -21 -24 -27 -29 -31 -33 -34 -36 -37 -36 -36 -36 -37 -37 -35 -35 -35 -35 -34 -32 -30
 -10 -2 17 -1 2 -17 -16 -11 5 -1 82 63 -10 -19 -21 -21 -20 -20 -19 -19 -18 -17 -16 -14 -11 -5 -1 -1 -1 -1 -12 -19 -21 -22 -23 -24 -25 -25 -26 -26 -26 -27 -27 -28 -28 -29 -29 -29 -28 -27 -25 -23 -21 -19 -17 -16 -16 -18 -20 -24 -27 -31 -33 -35 -36 -37 -38 -39 -39 -39 -39 -40 -40 -39 -38 -38 -37 -36 -34 -33
 -12 -13 -13 -12 -13 -13 -9 -6 13 5 32 5 -17 -22 -23 -23 -22 -21 -21 -20 -20 -19 -18 -16 -11 -3 -1 1 17 -1 -11 -23 -26 -26 -26 -26 -26 -26 -26 -27 -27 -27 -28 -28 -29 -30 -30 -30 -29 -28 -26 -24 -22 -20 -19 -19 -19 -21 -24 -27 -32 -36 -38 -39 -39 -40 -40 -40 -40 -40 -40 -41 -41 -41 -40 -39 -38 -37 -36 -35
 -14 -16 -17 -15 -14 -11 -7 -6 -6 -6 -14 -21 -24 -25 -25 -23 -22 -21 -21 -21 -21 -21 -20 -18 -15 -8 1 64 175 42 -8 -30 -32 -31 -29 -28 -28 -27 -27 -27 -27 -28 -28 -29 -29 -30 -31 -31 -31 -29 -28 -26 -24 -23 -22 -22 -23 -25 -27 -31 -35 -38 -40 -41 -41 -41 -40 -40 -39 -39 -39 -40 -40 -40 -40 -40 -39 -38 -37 -37
 -15 -16 -17 -16 -14 -12 -9 -9 -10 -13 -19 -24 -26 -26 -24 -23 -22 -21 -20 -20 -21 -21 -22 -21 -19 -16 -8 55 57 87 -4 -30 -33 -33 -31 -30 -29 -28 -28 -28 -28 -28 -28 -28 -29 -31 -32 -32 -32 -31 -29 -27 -26 -25 -26 -27 -29 -30 -32 -33 -36 -37 -38 -40 -41 -41 -40 -39 -39 -38 -38 -38 -39 -40 -40 -40 -40 -39 -38 -38
 -14 -16 -16 -16 -14 -13 -11 -11 -12 -15 -19 -23 -25 -25 -23 -21 -20 -18 -18 -18 -19 -21 -22 -21 -21 -22 -22 -16 -1 4 -13 -28 -32 -33 -32 -31 -30 -29 -29 -29 -28 -28 -28 -28 -29 -31 -32 -33 -33 -32 -30 -28 -27 -27 -29 -31 -34 -36 -36 -36 -35 -34 -35 -38 -40 -40 -40 -39 -39 -38 -38 -37 -38 -40 -41 -41 -41 -40 -39 -39
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical ASCII file format and you need to convert the file into raster using [ASCII to Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/ascii-to-raster.htm) tool. You can access the tool from `ArcToolbox -> Conversion Tools -> To Raster -> ASCII to Raster`. You can save the file as .tif for a TIFF file format, .img for an ERDAS IMAGINE file format, or no extension for an Esri Grid raster format.

Comment: Do you mean I need to save the .asc file as a .tff/.img etc ?

Comment: I updated my answer. You need to use a ASCII to Raster tool located in ArcToolbox -> Conversion Tools -> To Raster -> ASCII to Raster

Comment: As I said before, there is an error when I try to convert it to raster from asc2. And also, it doesn't let me put .tiff for the output.

Comment: Normally the file should has extension of .asc not asc2. Make a copy of the file and change the extension to asc and try again. The extension of output is .tif not .tiff

Comment: Nothing worked. :(   Just more errors.
Maybe theres something wrong in the asc2 data itself?

Comment: Try to change the name of ascii file to something simple like test.asc, and try again.

Comment: yep did that multiple times, still did not work

Comment: @DavidJrGbadago What is the precise error that you get when you run your "best" test?  Please update your question with the precise steps that lead to that error, and include the error as text rather than a picture.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here and I don't know how to show errors in text.

Comment: Since I can't use the asc2 file right now, may I ask about the .tif file that I showed above? How may I interpret the data?
I read this in the html file that was zipped with the other files: 
"Within the 1D netCDF file, the grid is stored as a one-dimensional array of 2-byte signed integer values of elevation in metres, with negative values for bathymetric depths and positive values for topographic heights."
Could this also apply to the .tif data where there are negative and positive numbers?

Comment: @DavidJrGbadago Just type in (or copy/paste) the error message instead of using a screenshot that cannot be searched.